# How to declare a return type correctly for querySelector(All) binds

Tags: typescript, bind, declare

I like to do this, just with correct types.

```js
const qs = document.querySelector.bind(document) as HTMLElementTagNameMap | null;
const qsa = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document) as NodeListOf<any>;
```

When hovering over `querySelectorAll` in codium I get lots of into like. return Type of `NodeListOf<...> (+2 overloads)` I do now know what those overloads are or mean <...> is not working, so I tried  ...

But this way I get Errors for `qsa` saying `NodeListOf<any> has no callable signatures`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to type it at all. TypeScript will happily infer the type:

```
const qs = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const qsa = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAjhGBeGATEwCuBbApmKAOjk1wCcBPAZVwBtdgoQzCAjASzFQAp0s8CASgDcAWABQoSLAQBDZGgw58REuWp0GTMgEFatNpx59lQseIlToMXAoTcARAGIAZiBAOREgPTeYACXJcABoYAANcMJh2RDCAUXoBWAAfGDBMfSjZRFwADwAHLVxUIA)

The problem with what you were doing was that you were giving the type of *result* that the functions provide, not the type of the *function*.

---

If you were defining a new function and for some reason TypeScript couldn't infer the type, in a type (not value) context, `typeof` can be used to get the type of something. For instance:

```
type QSFunction = typeof document.querySelector;
```

or

```
const qs = document.querySelector.bind(document) as typeof document.querySelector;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAjhGBeGATEwCuBbApmKAOjk1wCcBPAZVwBtdgoQzCAjASzFQAp0s8CAShgBDRFAoAHXCABmaDDnxES5anQZMyAbgCwAKFCRYCEcgX9lxUpRr1GzAIK1abTjz5Kho8VJnzPARUbdXstZ1o9fQMjaBhccwRuACIAYlkQEGTBKIB6XJgACXJcABoYAANcCph2RAqAUXogmAAfGDBMFxqxeIAPaUZcVCA)

Since the right-hand side of a `type` assignment or `as` is a type context, `typeof` there is TypeScript's `typeof`, not JavaScripts. Then you could do.

But again, no need for that here.

Comment: Your first statement is wrong for me. I am using Codium with an eslint-typescript setup and it's **not** inferring the type. Hovering over the functions without a type declared shows them as just returning type `any`.

Comment: I used the `as typeof document.querySelector` to make it work now so that is what I was looking for. null issues pop up in my code as expected.

Comment: @redanimalwar - The lack of inference is very odd. It sounds like a Codium or similar issue, not TypeScript itself, which definitely does infer that type, at least in modern versions. I'm not a TypeScript historian, but I don't think vigorous inference is a new feature. Still, it may be worth checking your TypeScript version.